# Does x = i++ in C have a defined behavior and why?

Tags: c, undefined

According to [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html), `i = i++` is a undefined behaviour in C because this statement has only one sequence point (full expression), and in this statement `i` has been changed twice (side effect of `i++` and `=`) so it is an undefined behaviour.

Question 1 is do I get that correctly? Or do I misunderstand why `i = i++` is undefined?

The second question is that is `x = i++` an valid expression?

I guess it is valid and the value of `x` will always be the origin value of `i`. Because although there is only one sequence point in this statement, but both x and i are modified only once, and `i++` has a higher precedence, which  means it should be valid and `x++` will always done before the assignment, make x equals to the origin value of x. Is that correct?

Comment: Short answer: Correct and correct.
Your explanations are also correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, at least as of C++03. I believe C++11 changes this somewhat, but I can't get my hands on a copy of that standard to check.
2. Because you modify `x` once, and `i` once. There's no multiple writes to a single variable without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: OP was asking about C not C++.  Looks like you over-applied the ++ operator. :)